# Can we connect an OSX computer to an AWS VPC VPN?

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have a OSX computer we would like to connect to our AWS VPC.

This OSX computer is on a network we do not control in a different physical location as the rest of our network.

Using OSXs Networking Software (in preferences) or other software VPN client, can we connect to AWS's Hardware VPN connection to the VPC?

If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Maybe a "Customer Gateway"?

Answer (score 1):

If you install/configure/start a VPN Server (e.g. using OpenVPN) in your AWS Envirnoment you can connect to your VPC with your client machine.

Comment: This does not answer the question "can we connect to AWS's Hardware VPN connection to the VPC?"

Comment: Okay, second try. If the question is whether it is possible to connect with a MacOS device to a AWS VPC then the answer is yes. AWS VPC has Site2Site VPN support using IPSec. If you install any IPSec on your MacOS (e.g. strongswan) you can connect your PC to AWS VPC.